# Drag drop jquery ui dialog box/ html / css

Tags: jquery, html5, css3, jquery-ui

Pessoal em uma aplicação gostaria de basicamente arrastar uma div que está dentro do dialog box e coloca-la em outra qualquer. Ao tentar fazer com meu codigo a div tende a sumir quando começo a arastar para fora. Segue link pra verificação. [veja o codigo](https://jsfiddle.net/wendelshm/xpvt214o/316675/)

Comment: O problema aí, que pelo menos eu percebi na documentação é que este **dialog** cria uma div própria com seu próprio **z-index** e não permite arrastar nada para fora deste espaço que ele cria, até por isso que nos exemplos lá na documentação o conteúdo destes dialogs são apenas texto, ou seja elementos estáticos.

Comment: No caso você quer tirar div "Selecionar Imagens" e colocar na div azul?

Comment: Não. Quero tira a div com a class="Tabimg" do dialog criado.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o problema. Ao fazer teste em outras div tipo janela modal, bastou colocar o **overflow** = *false* na propriedade css da div do modal. Tem nada haver o com o **z-index**. Obrigado pela ajuda de todos na resolução do problema.